# JavaFX ContextMenu how do I get the clicked Object?

Tags: javafx, contextmenu, eventhandler

I am learning javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu, and right now I am facing a problem:

how do I get the clicked Object from EventHandler? both event.source() and event.target() return the MenuItem.

let me explain with an example:
what should I write inside the function handle?

```
    TextField text = new TextField();
    Label label1 = new Label("hello");
    Label label2 = new Label("world");
    Label label3 = new Label("java");

    ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();
    MenuItem item = new MenuItem("copy to text field");
    menu.getItems().add(item);
    item.setOnAction(new EventHandler(){
        public void handle(Event event) {
            //I want to copy the text of the Label I clicked to TextField
            event.consume();
        }
    });

    label1.setContextMenu(menu);
    label2.setContextMenu(menu);
    label3.setContextMenu(menu);
```

EDIT: I was hoping there was some simple solution (one liner), but if there isn't then there are lot's of complex way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create your own instance of ContextMenu and add the action parent to it for further reference:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    TextField text = new TextField();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {


        Label label1 = new Label("hello");
        Label label2 = new Label("world");
        Label label3 = new Label("java");

        label1.setContextMenu(new MyContextMenu(label1));
        label2.setContextMenu(new MyContextMenu(label2));
        label3.setContextMenu(new MyContextMenu(label3));

        HBox root = new HBox();

        root.getChildren().addAll(text, label1, label2, label3);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 100);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    private class MyContextMenu extends ContextMenu {

        public MyContextMenu(Label label) {

            MenuItem item = new MenuItem("copy to text field");
            item.setOnAction(event -> {

                // I want to copy the text of the Label I clicked to TextField
                text.setText(label.getText());

                event.consume();
            });

            getItems().add(item);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: that's a good idea, but I was hoping such a functionality already existed.

Comment: possible - not my preference: extending is a rather "heavy" measure, if we do then the extension should do some "heavy" work, not just custom configuration. My personal cents :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way is to save the Node as UserData of context menu.

```
EventHandler<? super ContextMenuEvent> eventHandle = e->menu.setUseData(e.getSource());
label1.setOnContextMenuRequested(eventHandle );
label2.setOnContextMenuRequested(eventHandle );
label3.setOnContextMenuRequested(eventHandle );
```

and in action:

```
EventHandler<ActionEvent> menuItemEvent = e->{
    Node node = (Node) ((MenuItem)e.getSource()).getParentPopup().getUserData();
   ...
};
```

Answer (score 2):

To sum up the basic requirement: get hold of the node that a contextMenu was opened for. According to the api doc of PopupWindow (the grandparent of ContextMenu), that should be easy to achieve

[show(Node node, ...)](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/PopupWindow.html#show(javafx.scene.Node,double,double))

> ... The popup is associated with the specified owner node...

[Node getOwnerNode()](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/PopupWindow.html#getOwnerNode())

> The node which is the owner of this popup.

So the general approach in the action of a MenuItem is to

- get hold of the item's parentPopup (that's the contextMenu), might have to work up the ladder if there are nested menus
- grab its ownerNode
- access whatever property is needed

The example at the end does just that in copyText and verifies, that it is working as expected ... iff we are *not* using a control's contextMenuProperty. The reason for the not-working in controls is a method contract violation (probably [introduced by a bug fix](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8114638) around auto-hide behavior in textInputControls) of ContextMenu: it always uses the `show(Window w, ..)` after it has been set as contextMenu to any control (implementation detail: Control.contextMenuProperty sets a flag `setShowRelativeToWindow(true)` which triggers the mis-behavior)

Now what can we do to get hold of the ownerNode? There are several options, none of which is nice:

- as done in the other answers, somehow keep track of the ownerNode: by using factory method, by storing in the user properties or any other ad-hoc means
- extend ContextMenu, override `show(Node owner, ... )` and keep the given owner in a custom property
- extend ContextMenu, override `show(Node owner, ...)` go dirty and reflectively set super ownerNode to the given
- go dirty and reflectively reset the offending showRelativeToWindow flag back to false *after* setting the menu to any control

The first two introduce additional coupling, the latter (besides the dirty reflective access) might re-introduce problems with auto-hide (the "fixed" behavior is dirty in itself .. violating the "keep-open-if-owner-clicked" guarantee)

At the end, an example to play with:

```
public class ContextMenuOwnerSO extends Application {

    private Parent createContent() {

        TextField text = new TextField();
        // the general approach to grab a property from the Node
        // that the ContextMenu was opened on
        EventHandler<ActionEvent> copyText = e -> {
            MenuItem source = (MenuItem) e.getTarget();
            ContextMenu popup = source.getParentPopup();
            String ownerText = "<not available>";
            if (popup != null) {
                Node ownerNode = popup.getOwnerNode();
                if (ownerNode instanceof Labeled) {
                    ownerText = ((Label) ownerNode).getText();
                } else if (ownerNode instanceof Text) {
                    ownerText = ((Text) ownerNode).getText();
                }
            }
            text.setText(ownerText);
        };

        MenuItem printOwner = new MenuItem("copy to text field");
        printOwner.setOnAction(copyText);

        // verify with manual managing of contextMenu
        Text textNode = new Text("I DON'T HAVE a contextMenu property");
        Label textNode2 = new Label("I'm NOT USING the contextMenu property");
        ContextMenu nodeMenu = new ContextMenu();
        nodeMenu.getItems().addAll(printOwner);
        EventHandler<ContextMenuEvent> openRequest = e -> {
            nodeMenu.show((Node) e.getSource(), Side.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
            e.consume();
        };

        textNode.setOnContextMenuRequested(openRequest);
        textNode2.setOnContextMenuRequested(openRequest);

        Label label1 = new Label("I'm USING the contextMenu property");

        ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu() {

            // force menu to have an owner node: this being the case, it is not hidden 
            // on mouse events inside its owner
            //@Override
            //public void show(Node anchor, double screenX, double screenY) {
            //    ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<Node> owner = 
            //            (ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<Node>) 
            //            FXUtils.invokeGetFieldValue(PopupWindow.class, this, "ownerNode");
            //    owner.set(anchor);
            //    super.show(anchor, screenX, screenY);
            //}

        };
        MenuItem item = new MenuItem("copy to text field");
        menu.getItems().add(item);
        item.setOnAction(copyText);

        label1.setContextMenu(menu);
        // same effect as forcing the owner node 
        // has to be done after the last setting of contextMenuProperty 
        // setting to true was introduced as fix for
        // https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8114638
        //FXUtils.invokeGetMethodValue(ContextMenu.class, menu, "setShowRelativeToWindow", Boolean.TYPE, false);

        VBox content = new VBox(10, textNode, textNode2, text, label1);
        return content;

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setScene(new Scene(createContent(), 400, 200));
        stage.setTitle(FXUtils.version());
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger
            .getLogger(ContextMenuOwnerSO.class.getName());

}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. There is no reason to create a contextmenu for each node.

Comment: What is the FXUtils class that you are using? It does not exist in the official openjFX docs.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a different `ContextMenu` instance for each label:

```
TextField text = new TextField();
Label label1 = new Label("hello");
Label label2 = new Label("world");
Label label3 = new Label("java");

label1.setContextMenu(createContextMenu(label1, text));       
label2.setContextMenu(createContextMenu(label2, text));            
label3.setContextMenu(createContextMenu(label3, text));

// ...

private ContextMenu createContextMenu(Label label, TextField text) {
    ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();
    MenuItem item = new MenuItem("copy to text field");
    menu.getItems().add(item);
    item.setOnAction(new EventHandler(){
        public void handle(Event event) {
            text.setText(label.getText());
        }
    });
    return menu ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware it's been some time since it has been asked but as I was looking to solve my similiar problem with JavaFX context menu I ran into this thread and Oleksandr Potomkin answer gave me an idea on how to solve it.

What I wanted to achieve is a functioning ContextMenu (one for many fields) that would give me access to the control that opened context menu (or have been called by Accelerator) when I click MenuItem.

Also I had a problem with setting the Accelerator - it would work if I'm focused on form but wouldn't work if I'm focused on the desired control. It should be the other way around...

What I did is I created a class that would initialize a ContextMenu (in it's constructor) and share a method to link that context menu to desired controls:

```
public class FieldContextMenu {
    ContextMenu menu;
    MenuItem menuCopy;

    public FieldContextMenu() {
        menu = new ContextMenu();

        menuCopy = new MenuItem("Copy");
        menuCopy.setAccelerator(KeyCombination.keyCombination("Ctrl+C"));
        menuCopy.setOnAction(event -> System.out.println(((TextField) menu.getUserData()).getText()));

        menu.getItems().addAll(menuCopy);
    }

    public void link(Control ctrl) {
        ctrl.setContextMenu(menu);
        // onKeyPressed so KeyCombination work while focused on this control
        ctrl.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
            if(event.isControlDown() && event.getCode() == KeyCode.C) {
                menu.setUserData(ctrl);
                menuCopy.fire();
            }
        });
        // setting this control in menus UserData when ContextMenu is activated in this control
        ctrl.setOnContextMenuRequested(e -> menu.setUserData(ctrl));
    }
}
```

And here's how I use it in FXML Controller:

```
public class ExampleController {
    @FXML private AnchorPane rootPane;
    @FXML private TextField textField1;
    @FXML private TextField textField2;

    @FXML protected void initialize() {
        // consume roots keyPressed event so the accelerator wouldn't "run" when outside of the control
        rootPane.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
            if(event.isControlDown()) event.consume();
        });

        FieldContextMenu contextMenu = new FieldContextMenu();
        contextMenu.link(textField1);
        contextMenu.link(textField2);
    }
}
```

The way I'm doing it the ContextMenu gets initialized just once = less memory usage (if I'm thinking correctly).